# Aptana Studio : Code folds not being remembered

Tags: javascript, ide, aptana, folding

I have started using Aptana Studio 3 with a big JS document. It is quite importnt to me that code is folded to make the document more manageable. Unfortunately I keep finding that folded parts of the document become unfolded for some reason and that when I close and reopen a document the folds are no longer remembered.

**Is there a way to make code folds more permanent in Aptana?**

Answer (score 3):

I've not found a way to make code folds persistent but would love to know though

In the meantime I've been using the "collapse all" option combined with bookmarks.

When you open a file you can right click in the left margin and choose to collapse all (or CTRL+SHIFT+numpad divide) - If working on a code block you can attach a Bookmark also by right clicking in left margin, then from Bookmarks View when you double click the bookmark it expands just that code block and takes you to it

To open Bookmarks View in bottom pane: `Window > Show View > Other > General > Bookmarks`

Answer (score 2):

There may be two issues at work here:

1) Code will unfold if it's in an error state (i.e. the document is malformed). There was some work done to prevent this from happening all the time, but if there is a particular use case you run into often, I'd suggest filing a bug about it so that the developers can take a look.

2) Particular code folds are not saved across open/closes of editors. However, you may be interested to know that in version 3.0.2, initial folding of code blocks will be configurable, so you can set some items to auto-start as folded.